# Overshoot control

Tags: control-system

Suppose I have the following step response:
$$y_{step}(t)=\frac{kP}{1+kP}(1-e^{\frac{-t}{\tau}})$$
where k is constant and P is the plant.
How may I determine the values of k for which there would be no overshoot?

Comment: Are there *any* values of \$k\$ for which there is overshoot?

Comment: But how may I check for these values? Given a certain function, how does one normally check for potential overshoots? Do I simply check whether y_step(t) exceeds 1?

Comment: For a time domain expression, if a function does *not* overshoot or undershoot but steadily approaches the 'final' value, what does that imply about the (time) derivative of the function?

Answer (score 1):

The *particular* step response you show can't overshoot, as k and P are constants. The dynamics of the step response are determined by the exponential function only.

In *general*, you can check if a *linear* system will overshoot with a step input by analyzing its frequency response.

The maximum value of the Bode plot of magnitude is related to the overshoot you will have, given a step input, because the step input excites your system [at every frequency](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT4/node2.html).

If the maximum of the [Bode plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bode_plot) of magnitude of a closed-loop system is 1 (or less, allowing a [steady-state error](http://www.cds.caltech.edu/~murray/amwiki/index.php/FAQ%3a_What_is_steady_state_error?) as in the closed-loop system you brought as an example) you have no overshoot.

You could find the topic of [critical damping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damping) interesting, too.

Comment: P might not be linear.  VERY true for a 1st order plant & the rest of this there should not be any overshoot. But a 2nd order plant with a high proportional aspect to it?

Comment: Actually, P(s)=s^2+a1*s+a0 and Y_step(s)=[kP(s)]/[1+kP(s)]. For what values of k will there be no overshoot?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no overshoot, then, mathematically, it means that the function monotonically increases toward the limiting value at high values of t (which is just the fraction without the exponential factor). This means that its derivative of the function stays positive.

Overshoot means that the function rises and then falls. When it switches from rising to falling, its slope becomes zero very briefly and then negative.

You can analyze the derivative, looking for values of k which make it touch or cross zero.

Comment: Is there any way to check for overshoots without having to use an inverse Laplace (I mean, how else could I determine the derivative wrt time)? My initial expression for y(t) is most likely incorrect.

Comment: You mean the \$y_\text{step}(t)\$ function isn't necessarily the right one? If it is the actual step function, then it represents the actual time-domain response, and it boils down to, for what values of the parameters does the function not show a "hump".